# CAGradientLayer color generation algorithm

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm generating gradients in my code, but the algorithm I'm using is clearly different than what is used to generate gradients within CAGradientLayer.  Does anyone know how it goes about generating the colors it does?

Comment: I would assume it's a linear interpolation between the stops, or if not linear, then cubic. Can you post the code you're using to generate the colors and perhaps an image showing the difference between yours and theirs?

Comment: Note also the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/locations) say "When rendered, the colors are mapped to the output color space before being interpolated."